# Встроенные компиляторы и интерпретаторы Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Не могу найти список встроенных компиляторов и интерпретаторов  Ubuntu. Те , которые установлены по умолчанию из коробки

Comment: По-моему нет таких.Все устанавливать надо

Comment: Если python и bash считать компиляторами, то они всегда есть.

Comment: @avp а для си и си++ есть что-то встроенное?

Comment: @avp они интерпретаторы

Comment: @HideME нет. Ставь пакет build-essential

Comment: @AlexeyTen я сам перепутал, так какие есть интерпретаторы и компиляторы встроенные, все назвали?

Comment: @HideME, вам важно получать исполняемый модуль именно в виде заранее сделанных машинных инструкций? Тогда, безусловно, нужен компилятор. А почему интерес именно к встроенным? Установить очень легко -- apt-get ... (конкретные аргументы ищутся в сети) и вперед.

Comment: @avp у меня задание такое, нужно написать список, что можно устанавливать я уже узнал, нужно именно встроенное, до этого не работал на линуксоидах, вот и спрашиваю

Comment: для начала бы найти просто минимальный набор пакетов без которых юбунта не ставится. А из них уже выделять. потому что как по мне питон и bash излишни в минимальной системе. Что до интерпретаторов надо бы уточнить какие интерпретаторы, потому что если рассматривать хотя бы любые полные по Тьюрингу языки, то надо учитывать еще sed и awk, очень сомневаюсь, что есть инсталяции без них

Comment: @Mike система, если мы о той, которая с пользовательским интерфейсом, как минимум должен быть какой-то shell. Так что в неэкзотическом случае всегда есть один интерпретатор. А дальше уже могут быть варианты.

Comment: @0andriy Ну тут вопрос в "минимальности". Практически все встраиваемые linux системы например используют busybox. потому что это фактически один исполнимый файл, включающий в себя все жизненно необходимые команды, включая ash в качестве shell. А вот возможна ли инсталляция ubuntu с основой из бизибокса, это надо смотреть

Comment: *из коробки* — «коробки» бывают очень-очень разные. даже с учётом того, что среди надписей на них мелькает слово «ubuntu».

Comment: Есть вот такой iso не в курсе все ли его блюдут https://www.iso.org/standard/43781.html